# Adding a JTable to my Pane Inside a Dialog Throws an NPE when I pack it

Tags: swing, jtable, jdialog, jtabbedpane, formpanel

I have created a `JDialog`. When it comes up, I have a `JTabbedPane` that has several `FormPanel`s on it. The form panels are loaded in as a form file (I used [Abeille](http://java.net/projects/abeille) to create the forms.) I have had no problems until I tried to add a `JTable` to one of the forms (again, through Abeille.)  I add the form like I did the rest of the tabs, but when I run `dialog.pack`, it throws a `NullPointerException`.  The table inside that form does not appear to be `null` as I can get values from it. I cannot see what is causing the `null`.

```
private JDialog m_dialog;
private FormPanel m_panelForm;
private FormPanel m_tableEditorForm;
private FormPanel m_fieldEditorForm;
private FormPanel m_seedDataEditorForm;

JFrame appFrame = App.getInstance().getFrame();
m_dialog = new JDialog(appFrame, "Dialog Title"), true);
m_dialog.setName("Dialog"));
m_dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(appFrame);

// Load dialog layout
m_panelForm = getFormPanel("DLG_EDIT_PANEL");
m_tableEditorForm = getFormPanel("DLG_TABLE_EDITOR");
m_fieldEditorForm = getFormPanel("DLG_FIELD_EDITOR");
m_seedDataEditorForm = getFormPanel("DLG_SEED_DATA_EDITOR");

JTabbedPane pane = m_panelForm.getTabbedPane("editPane");

//Set up the tabs
pane.insertTab("Table", null, m_tableEditorForm, null, 0);
pane.insertTab("Field", null, m_fieldEditorForm, null, 1);
pane.insertTab("Seed", null, m_seedDataEditorForm, null, 2);

m_panelForm.reset();

m_dialog.setContentPane(m_panelForm);
m_dialog.pack();
```

The third insert, the one called "Seed" is the one that blows it out; if I comment out the line the other tabs show up fine. Similarly, if I remove the `JTable` from the form in Abeille the tab shows up fine.

Note the `columnCount` and `rowCount` defaults to 2. Also note that if I turn off pack, I have a `setVisible` off of the `JDialog` that throws the same error.

Any help would be appreciated; I'm okay at Swing but far from good.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jeta.open.support.DefaultComponentFinder.unregisterComponent(Unknown Source)
    at com.jeta.open.support.DefaultComponentFinder.componentRemoved(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentRemoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:193)
    at java.awt.Container.processContainerEvent(Container.java:2070)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2038)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.Container.remove(Container.java:1162)
    at java.awt.Container.remove(Container.java:1198)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1046)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:927)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI.updateColumnHeader(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:606)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.scrollPanePropertyChange(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:1102)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.propertyChange(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:1079)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:339)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:276)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8154)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane.setColumnHeader(JScrollPane.java:1095)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(JScrollPane.java:1120)
    at javax.swing.JTable.configureEnclosingScrollPane(JTable.java:713)
    at javax.swing.JTable.addNotify(JTable.java:684)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:739)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:663)
    at java.awt.Dialog.addNotify(Dialog.java:743)
    at java.awt.Window.pack(Window.java:704)
    at com.follett.fsc.core.utils.schema.workbench.gui.dialogs.EditTableDialog.showDialog(EditTableDialog.java:108)
    at com.follett.fsc.core.utils.schema.workbench.gui.components.Tab.doEditTableRow(Tab.java:1354)
    at com.follett.fsc.core.utils.schema.workbench.gui.components.Tab.doEditRow(Tab.java:1437)
    at com.follett.fsc.core.utils.schema.workbench.gui.components.Tab$17$1.run(Tab.java:1016)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:612)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)?

Comment: Good advice. I've done that and it does reproduced; but at least I know it's the way I am doing it as opposed to any underlying code.

Comment: I guess you mean "the problem is **not** reproduced in the short code".  An NPE in a Swing GUI is often caused by updating components off the EDT.  Do you have any other threads explicitly running in the application?

Comment: Sorry, that was some poor English... I meant to say it IS reproducible with the short code.   I figured out that it works fine when I try to add it to a regular frame as opposed to a dialog. I am now attempting to add a JTable manually to a dialog.

Comment: Does the exception also appear when you simply call setVisible(true) on the dialog without packing?

Comment: It does. I've tried several different methods using the form; I can manually add a table to a form I have created, but it does not work using the form in combination with a dialog.